# How to check the types of Exceptions thrown in a catch block?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, sqlexception, catch-block

I have something like this:

```
catch (Exception ex)
 {
      if (ex is "Exception Type")
      {

      }
      else if (ex is SqlException)
      {

      }
      else if 
      {
        ...
        ...
        ...
 }
```

Is this right in `C#` and what does the `is` mean anyway, which is its role or is there another way?

Comment: you can just have multiple catch blocks: `catch(MyException1 ex){...}catch(MyException2 
 ex){...}`

Comment: @GuruStron, how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is another way. By calling the specific exceptions that could possibly occur when running a block of code:

```
try {
   // Do something
}
catch(SqlException ex) {

}
catch(AnotherException ex) {

}
```

Then it is very important to start with the most specific exception and work your way towards a general exception.

Comment: Is it really valid C# code? `try` and `catch` will start from lower case letters. type of variable comes before the variable name, not the after

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Yes, C# is case sensitive. Edited my example to be more correct.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski , what keyword `is` means  anyway in C# , is it right?

Comment: What keyword `is` means anyway in C# , is it right?

Comment: @LopDev See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#is-operator and maybe also  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is

Answer (score 2):

Multiple catch blocks is an answer([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch#two-catch-blocks-example)):

```
try
{
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    ...    
}
catch(AnotherExceptionType ex)
{
     ...
}
```

you can add as many as you like after your `try` block.

**UPD**
As added in comments to this answer - order is important, so if you have exceptions hierarchy catch derived ones first.

Comment: Heads up: Order will be important if one Exception type is derived from another. For example: if your _first_ catch block catches `Exception`, that's the only one that will ever be hit.

Comment: @Fildor i thought compiler nowadays is pretty good at determining most of such situations =) But yes, valid point.

Comment: @GuruStron not in this specific case

Comment: @GuruStron I guess there should probably be a warning, yes. Not sure, though.

Comment: What keyword `is` means anyway in C# , is it right?

Comment: @LopDev [is keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) and [type-testing operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#is-operator)

Answer (score 2):

Classic option:

```
try
{
    return DoStuff();    
}
catch (InvalidOperationException opEx)
{
    return HandleInvalidOp(opEx);
}
catch (DivideByZeroException divEx)
{
    return HandleDivException(divEx);
}
catch (Exception ex)  // final catch-all
{
    return HandleEx(ex);
}
```

Using pattern matching switch:

```
try
{
    return DoStuff();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    switch (ex)
    {
        case InvalidOperationException opEx:
            return HandleInvalidOp(opEx);
        case DivideByZeroException divEx:
            return HandleDivException(divEx);
        default:
            return HandleEx(ex);
    }
}
```